# HTML5: Rendering absolute images using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am experimenting with canvas as part of my HTML5 introduction. This constitutes as assignment work, but I am not asking for any help on the actual coursework at all.

I am trying to write a rendering engine, but having no luck because once the image is drawn on  canvas it looks very distorted, and not at the right dimensions of the image itself.

I have made a animation engine that loads images into an array, and then iterates through them at a certain speed. This is not the problem, and I assume is not causing the issue as this was happening when I drawn an image to the canvas without the animation component.

I think this is natural behaviour for images to be scaled/skewed when the window is resized, so I conquered that by simply redrawing the whole thing once the window is resized.

The images I am using are isometric, and drawn at a pixel level. Would this cause the distortion? It seems setting the dimensions on the drawImage() function are not working are all. I am using JavaScript for the manipulation and rendering of the canvas.

I would normally try and work it out myself, but I do not have any time to ponder why because I have no idea why it is even scaling/skewing the image once it is drawn on the canvas. I cannot share the code for obvious reasons. I should also mention, the canvas's dimension is the total width of the viewport, as I am developing a game.

My question is: Has anyone encountered this and how would I correct it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you set dimensions of canvas with css.
Try defining them as html attributes. Example:

```
<canvas id="test" width="100" height="100">Fallback content</canvas>
```

Edit:
It will set width/height of canvas element to 100/100 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not make any difference. I tried using the HTML attributes to resize it at first, and it seemed to treat 100 as pixels. Using percentage seemed to not work either, so I did it with CSS and also JS to ensure it is 100% in X and Y. It is very weird.

Comment: These are pixels (without %). Try creating clean HTML page with only one canvas element and dimensions set to 1000/1000 pixels (without any css). If it still won't work as desired you will have to rethink your javascript code once again.

Comment: Yes, the problem was I was setting the canvas's dimensions with CSS. The canvas element is treated like an image, and I was actually scaling the canvas with CSS not resizing it. Thanks for the help. – Mark just now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was I was setting the canvas's dimensions with CSS. The canvas element is treated like an image, and I was actually scaling the canvas with CSS not resizing it. Thanks for the help. – Mark just now